# jquery function inside datalist control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

```js
$(function () {
  $('a.detials').on('click', function (ev) {
    $(this).next('div').toggle();
  });
});
```

the issue here is i want to toogle the div when anchor tag click .but i have the problem with my code i don't what is wrong.i search on google  to reach to this result and when i click on the anchor tag the div not open ,i need help .

$( function () {
        $('a.detials').on('click', function() {
            $('+ div', this).toggle();``
        });
    });

```html
<asp:DataList ID="dtlRoomsPrice" Visible="false" orizontalAlign="center" runat="server" ShowFooter="False" ShowHeader="False" Width="700px" OnItemDataBound="dtlRoomsDetails_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="detials">ShowDetails</a>
   <div class="shoow" id="div_ID" style="width:687px;height:110px;background-color:rgb(247,239, 216);border-radius: 5px;box-shadow: 7px 6px 5px #888888; border: 2px solid gray; display:none;padding: 5px; ">
                <asp:Label ID="lblAmiintiesTxt" runat="Server" CssClass="shbe_label" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,Amenities %>" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblAmiinties" runat="Server" CssClass="shbe_h2" Text='<%# Eval("Amenities") %>' Visible="true"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there's no click handler assigned for the first click.  This is what's happening:

1. User clicks on element
2. Function `togglee` is invoked
3. A click handler is assigned to element
4. User clicks on element again
5. Click handler is invoked (what you wanted to happen in the first click)
6. (Also, *another* click handler is added by invoking `togglee` again.  Which is definitely not what you want.)

I'm not sure why you're using this `togglee` function, but you don't need it.  Remove the inline JavaScript from the element:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="detials">ShowDetails</a>
```

and assign the click handler when the page loads:

```
$(function () {
    $('a.detials').on('click', function() {
        $('+ div', this).toggle();
    });
});
```

Then the first click on that element (and any subsequent click) will invoke that click handler.

Comment: @boshkash: Define "not working".  What is the actual code you wrote?  How does it fail?

Comment: the div not open, the function also.

Comment: @boshkash: Please try to understand that I can't see what's happening on your computer, nor can I debug your code on your computer for you.  If you have code that isn't working, please include it in the question.  Also please step through that code in a debugger and determine more specifically where/how it fails.  Currently all you're saying is, "There's some code on my computer that isn't working."  Nobody can help with that.

Comment: the problem here when i remove the on click event <a href="javascript:void(0);"  class="detials" onclick="javascript:togglee(); return false;" >ShowDetails</a>

Comment: @boshkash: The problem with the original code was that you used that inline event handler and `togglee` function in the first place.  This answer corrects that problem.  However, I can't know if you correctly *applied* this answer without seeing updated code.  Again, and I can't stress this enough, *I can't see what you're looking at.  I'm not actually inside your computer.*